# How to make this script into fade animation

Tags: javascript

Could someone help me on how to make this into fade animation instead of simple slide effect. I'm newbie when it comes in javascript. I can't figure it out on how to do this in fade animation. I like this script because its simple. If there's any jquery that something like this, please do share. Here's the code I've found below. Thanks in advance :)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<style>
body{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50 50;
}
</style>
<script >
//Specify background images to slide
var imgs=new Array()
imgs[0]="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-1.jpg";
imgs[1]="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-2.jpg";
imgs[2]="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-3.jpg";
//Specify interval between slide (in miliseconds)
var speed=3000
//preload images
var processed=new Array()
for (i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
processed[i]=new Image();
processed[i].src=imgs[i];
}
var inc=-1;
function slideimg(){
if (inc<imgs.length-1)
inc++;
else
inc=0;
document.body.background=processed[inc].src;
setTimeout(function(){
        slideimg();
    }, speed);
}

window.onload = function () {
    slideimg();
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="table1" height="381">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>This is just dummy text</p>
            <p>This is just dummy text</p>
            <p>This is just dummy text</p>
            <p>This is just dummy text</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Personally I'd use jQuery to make this easier to code and cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Not a real answer, so just adding as a comment, but just google for "Fade animation javascript". Here is first tutorial I found: http://tech.pro/tutorial/725/javascript-tutorial-simple-fade-animation

Comment: Normally I wouldn't answer a question by linking to jQuery, but since your script hadn't even started on the task of fading, I thought it the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a fade in JavaScript is not impossible, but has been done hundreds of times to the point where you shouldn't spend your time re-inventing it. I suggest you pick up a fade script via a simple search and de-construct it, if you really want to know how it works, or just use jQuery to do this. Personally, I think jQuery is the bomb diggadity.

[jQuery Fades](http://api.jquery.com/?s=fade)